# RuntimeError: Dst tensor is not initialized in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, gpu

I got

> RuntimeError: Dst tensor is not initialized

during the training of my neural network. Specifically, it seems that the error appears when in my custom `Callback` I get the predictions using `self.model.predict(self.dataset)` because the stack trace says

> File "mlp_keras.py", line 20, in on_epoch_end
>           predictions = self.model.predict(self.dataset)

This is the full stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mlp_keras.py", line 150, in <module>
    callbacks=[KendallTauHistory(training_dataset, training_dataset_labels, groups_id_count)])
  File "/usr/home/studenti/sp171412/word_ordering/mlp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 819, in fit
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
  File "/usr/home/studenti/sp171412/word_ordering/mlp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py", line 397, in fit
    prefix='val_')
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 24, in __exit__
    self.gen.next()
  File "/usr/home/studenti/sp171412/word_ordering/mlp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py", line 771, in on_epoch
    self.callbacks.on_epoch_end(epoch, epoch_logs)
  File "/usr/home/studenti/sp171412/word_ordering/mlp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/callbacks.py", line 302, in on_epoch_end
    callback.on_epoch_end(epoch, logs)
  File "mlp_keras.py", line 20, in on_epoch_end
    predictions = self.model.predict(self.dataset)
  File "/usr/home/studenti/sp171412/word_ordering/mlp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1013, in predict
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
  File "/usr/home/studenti/sp171412/word_ordering/mlp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py", line 498, in predict
    workers=workers, use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/home/studenti/sp171412/word_ordering/mlp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py", line 426, in _model_iteration
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
  File "/usr/home/studenti/sp171412/word_ordering/mlp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py", line 706, in _process_inputs
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
  File "/usr/home/studenti/sp171412/word_ordering/mlp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py", line 357, in __init__
    dataset = self.slice_inputs(indices_dataset, inputs)
  File "/usr/home/studenti/sp171412/word_ordering/mlp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py", line 383, in slice_inputs
    dataset_ops.DatasetV2.from_tensors(inputs).repeat()
  File "/usr/home/studenti/sp171412/word_ordering/mlp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 566, in from_tensors
    return TensorDataset(tensors)
  File "/usr/home/studenti/sp171412/word_ordering/mlp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 2765, in __init__
    element = structure.normalize_element(element)
  File "/usr/home/studenti/sp171412/word_ordering/mlp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/data/util/structure.py", line 113, in normalize_element
    ops.convert_to_tensor(t, name="component_%d" % i))
  File "/usr/home/studenti/sp171412/word_ordering/mlp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 1314, in convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "/usr/home/studenti/sp171412/word_ordering/mlp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/tensor_conversion_registry.py", line 52, in _default_conversion_function
    return constant_op.constant(value, dtype, name=name)
  File "/usr/home/studenti/sp171412/word_ordering/mlp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 258, in constant
    allow_broadcast=True)
  File "/usr/home/studenti/sp171412/word_ordering/mlp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 266, in _constant_impl
    t = convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
  File "/usr/home/studenti/sp171412/word_ordering/mlp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 96, in convert_to_eager_tensor
    return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
RuntimeError: Dst tensor is not initialized.
```

This is my code:

```
class KendallTauHistory(Callback):
      def __init__(self, dataset, y_true, groups):
        self.y_true = y_true
        self.dataset = dataset
        self.groups = groups

      def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        predictions = self.model.predict(self.dataset)
        predictions = predictions.flatten()
        predictions = list(map(lambda element: element + np.random.uniform(0.0, 1.0) * 0.02 - 0.01, predictions))
        # For batch training
        ranked_predictions = np.array([])
        kendalls = np.array([])
        start_range = 0
        for group in self.groups:
            end_range = (start_range + group[1]) # Batch is a group of words with same group id
            batch_predictions = predictions[start_range:end_range]
            batch_labels = self.y_true[start_range:end_range]
            batch_predictions = list(map(lambda element: element + np.random.uniform(0.0, 1.0) * 0.02 - 0.01, batch_predictions))
            ranked_predictions = np.append(ranked_predictions, np.floor(rankdata(batch_predictions)))
            kendalls = np.append(kendalls, kendalltau(batch_labels, batch_predictions))
            start_range = end_range
        #self.y_true = self.y_true[0:len(ranked_predictions)]
        print('\nORIGINAL LABELS: {0}\n'.format(self.y_true))
        print('PREDICTED LABELS: {0}'.format(ranked_predictions))
        print("\nEpoch Kendall's tau: {0}".format(np.mean(kendalls)))


    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(units=10, batch_input_shape=(None, 2, 839)))
    model.add(Dense(15, activation='sigmoid'))

    model.summary()

    model.compile(loss=listnet_loss, optimizer=keras.optimizers.Nadam(learning_rate=0.000005, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999))
    real_labels = np.array([])
    losses = np.array([])

    with tf.device('/GPU:0'):
      model.fit(training_dataset, training_dataset_labels, epochs=10, workers=10,
                verbose=1, callbacks=[KendallTauHistory(training_dataset, training_dataset_labels, groups_id_count)])
```

Comment: Is this the correct way of doing things? Shouldn't compilation of the model be done within with tf.device('/GPU:0') whereas fit doesn't have to be? Have you resolved the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Usually this error springs from the fact that your GPU remains out of memory while trying to allocate a tensor. In fact, I had the same error one week ago while training on a multi-gpu environment with CUDA 10.0 and TensorFlow 1.13.0.

My suggestion is to reduce the `batch_size` parameter in your `.fit()` method. If you did not explicitly define it, then it is set on 32. Gradually reduce by a factor of 2 in order to see your error gone.

You can also read about this error at this link: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7025

> (Getting "Dst tensor is not initialized." when really the problem is
>   out of GPU memory)

The error may be misleading, since it is not aligned with "OOM error" which is typical to TensorFlow when memory allocation problems appear.

Comment: thank you, I notice that I post a not updated code: my current ```batch_size``` is 2.

Comment: Please also update to Python at least 3.6; also, can you please tell me what GPU you are using

Comment: Python3 might be a problem because I'm on a remote machine and I think pip3 is not installed. The GPU is a Tesla P100

Comment: If you carefully read the stack-trace in the link that I provided this error only springs up due to memory issues.

Comment: In your self.model.predict(...., batch_size = 2). See if it works like this.

Comment: Must be related to that exact line if it does not break during the training.

Comment: Nothing changes unfortunately.