# InternalError: Dst tensor is not initialized when doing KFold Cross Validation in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, cross-validation

I am trying to get mean absolute error (MAE) for each split of data using 5-fold (KFold) cross validation. I have built a custom model using Xception that takes a X-ray hand image as an input and outputs estimated age in months. When I run the **for loop** for `kf.split(X_train)` in the code below (Under `cv_mae` part), I get an output for the first CV run. However, after the first CV run, I get the following error:

```py
640/640 [==============================] - 86s 114ms/step - loss: 0.3346 - mae_months: 17.8703

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InternalError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [15], in <cell line: 3>()
      3 for train_index, val_index in kf.split(X_train):
      4     model.fit(X_train[train_index], y_train[train_index], batch_size = 10)
----> 5     pred = model.predict(X_train[val_index], batch_size = 2)
      6     err = mean_absolute_error(y_train[val_index], pred)
      7     cv_mae.append(err)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\wrappers\scikit_learn.py:364, in KerasRegressor.predict(self, x, **kwargs)
    350 """Returns predictions for the given test data.
    351 
    352 Args:
   (...)
    361         Predictions.
    362 """
    363 kwargs = self.filter_sk_params(Sequential.predict, kwargs)
--> 364 return np.squeeze(self.model.predict(x, **kwargs))

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py:67, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     65 except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
     66   filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
---> 67   raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     68 finally:
     69   del filtered_tb

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py:102, in convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
    100     dtype = dtypes.as_dtype(dtype).as_datatype_enum
    101 ctx.ensure_initialized()
--> 102 return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)

InternalError: Failed copying input tensor from /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 in order to run _EagerConst: Dst tensor is not initialized.
```

> InternalError: Failed copying input tensor from /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 to
> /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 in order to run _EagerConst: Dst tensor is not initialized.

It seems the error appears every time when it comes across `model.predict()` because the error message states:

> ----> 5     pred = model.predict(X_train[val_index], batch_size = 2)

Code:

```py
# Checking the GPU availability
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')))

physical_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Root path for the image files:
root = 'P:/BoneDataset/0-Dataset/ba-trainset/'
age_df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(root, 'ba-training-dataset.csv'))

# Converting 'male' column to have male and female instead of true and false:
age_df['gender'] = age_df['male'].map(lambda x: 'male' if x else 'female')

# Checking for the path existance
age_df['path'] = age_df['id'].map(lambda x: os.path.join(root, 'ba-trainset', '{}.png'.format(x)))
age_df['exists'] = age_df['path'].map(os.path.exists)
print(age_df['exists'].sum(), 'images found of total of', age_df.shape[0], 'images.')

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Oldest children age in the dataset:
print('Maximum age: ' + str(age_df['boneage'].max()) + ' months')

# Youngest children age in the dataset:
print('Minimum age: ' + str(age_df['boneage'].min()) + ' months')

# Mean of children age in the dataset: 
boneage_mean = age_df['boneage'].mean()
print('Mean BA: ' + str(boneage_mean))

# Median of children age in the dataset: 
print('Median BA: ' + str(age_df['boneage'].median()))

# Standard deviation of children age in the dataset: 
boneage_div = age_df['boneage'].std()

# Normalizing features (models perform better) to have Zero Mean, and 
# Unified Standard Deviation using Z-score for training:
age_df['boneage_zscore'] = age_df['boneage'].map(lambda x: (x-boneage_mean)/boneage_div)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Trimming data size to 10000 from 12000
age_df['boneage_category'] = pd.cut(age_df['boneage'], 10)
new_age_df = age_df.groupby(['boneage_category', 'male']).apply(lambda x: x.sample(500, replace = True)).reset_index(drop = True)
print('New Data Size:', new_age_df.shape[0], 'Old Size:', age_df.shape[0])

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

train_df, valid_df = train_test_split(new_age_df, test_size = 0.20, stratify = new_age_df['boneage_category'])

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

## Image preprocessing:
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input
from keras.applications.imagenet_utils import preprocess_input

IMG_SIZE = (224, 224)
core_idg = ImageDataGenerator(samplewise_center = True, 
                              samplewise_std_normalization = True,
                              height_shift_range = 0.05,
                              width_shift_range = 0.05, 
                              rotation_range = 10, 
                              fill_mode = 'nearest',
                              rescale = 1. / 255,
                              preprocessing_function = preprocess_input)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def flow_from_dataframe(img_data_gen, in_df, path_col, y_col, **dflow_args):
    base_dir = os.path.dirname(in_df[path_col].values[0])
    print('## Ignore next message from keras, values are replaced anyways')
    df_gen = img_data_gen.flow_from_directory(base_dir, class_mode = 'sparse', **dflow_args)
    df_gen.filenames = in_df[path_col].values
    
    # Added df_gen.filepaths.extend because the filepaths is empty list. 
    # Hence added image path to the filepaths.
    df_gen.filepaths.extend(df_gen.filenames) 
    
    df_gen.classes = np.stack(in_df[y_col].values)
    df_gen.samples = in_df.shape[0]
    df_gen.n = in_df.shape[0]
    df_gen._set_index_array()
    df_gen.directory = '' # since we have the full path
    print('Reinserting dataframe: {} images'.format(in_df.shape[0]))
    return df_gen

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Data Generators:
train_gen = flow_from_dataframe(core_idg, train_df, 
                                path_col = 'path',
                                y_col = 'boneage_zscore', 
                                target_size = IMG_SIZE,
                                color_mode = 'rgb',
                                batch_size = len(train_df),
                                shuffle = True)

X_train, y_train = next(train_gen)

def boneage_model():
    
    base_model = Xception(input_shape = X_train.shape[1:], include_top = False, weights = 'imagenet')
    base_model.trainable = True

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(base_model)
    model.add(GlobalMaxPooling2D())
    model.add(Flatten())

    model.add(Dense(16, activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'linear'))

    def mae_months(in_gt, in_pred):
        return mean_absolute_error(boneage_div * in_gt, boneage_div * in_pred) 

    # Compile model
    adam = Adam(learning_rate = 0.0005)
    model.compile(loss = 'mse', optimizer = adam, metrics = [mae_months])
    
    return model

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# KFold
n_splits = 5
kf = KFold(n_splits = n_splits, shuffle = True, random_state = 42)

# create model
model = KerasRegressor(build_fn = boneage_model)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#### THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR STARTS 
cv_mae = []

for train_index, val_index in kf.split(X_train):
    model.fit(X_train[train_index], y_train[train_index], batch_size = 16)
    pred = model.predict(X_train[val_index], batch_size = 2)
    err = mean_absolute_error(y_train[val_index], pred)
    cv_mae.append(err)

cv_mae
```

Note! `train_df` has a value of 8000 images of X-ray hand images.

According to the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60378450/runtimeerror-dst-tensor-is-not-initialized-in-tensorflow), it suggests trimming the batch_size down, hence why the batch_size = 2 above at the `model.predict()`. However, it still prints out the same error message. Please help!

Comment: How much available memory does your GPU have between iterations? In my experience, you might need however much memory one iteration requires * the number of iterations because tensorflow doens't always free up memory.

Comment: So I am using the RTX 3060TI with 8GB RAM memory. I don't know how much memory my GPU have between iterations though....

Comment: Follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34199233/how-to-prevent-tensorflow-from-allocating-the-totality-of-a-gpu-memory - tensorflow will then just use what's needed.

Comment: I already applied their method on my code before and still get the same error message as above-mentioned...  Is it because after every split, it stores the data as memory that the memory ain't available for the next split?

Comment: So how much available memory does your GPU have between iterations?